# No access to subdirectory because of htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using a htaccess file on my main directory. It's from a cms I'm using. The problem is that I cannot get access to subdirectory because of it. What would I need to change, to get access to domain.com/cms?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first rule is unrelated. The second rule will cause all url's that don't start with public to be prefixed with public. `example.com/cms/cookies` will become `example.com/public/cms/cookies` internally. What you want is to exclude that from the rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public|cms)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You can expand that with any other subdirectories  you don't want the rule to match for. I am surprised you didn't get an internal server error, because as far as I know, `%{REQUEST_URI}` will always start with a slash. I have added that slash in my answer.

Comment: I have no clue what you expect to show up there. [This](http://bruteforce.tv/public/)? The rest of your site is on a subdomain, so your rule doesn't even match. [This](http://bruteforce.tv/) gives a forbidden error. There is too much you don't tell here.

Comment: Alright. In my root directory is the htaccess file place you just edited. The issue is that I cant access to my other website in the directory /cms because of the htacess file in my root directory. I need to edit it so that I can run /cms like there is no htaccess file in the root directory.